# Is this the right regression to use?

Tags: regression

Background: I have data on breakout of diarrhea in 67 villages. First, I wanted to use prevalence (calculated as number of diarrhea cases divided by number of households in the village) as my dependent variable. then, my independent variables are the access to water (categorical variable) and sanitation services (also categorical).

i tried using linear regression but looking at the distribution of data, it seems that this is very odd. and the errors are very heteroskedastic. i didn't know what else to do so i decided to switch my dependent variable back to cases of cholera.

so, with this switch, i now have count as a dependent variable. i decided to use zero inflated poisson distribution since there is overinflation of 0s in my data (tested for dispersion already).

is my approach reasonable? also, is 67 villages enough for this regression?

Added data below:

dependent variables:

1. prev = prevalence of diarrhea in village (cases divided by # of
   households) **-> used only for the linear regression attempt**
2. cases = number of diarrhea cases in village  **-> used for the zero inflated poisson regression attempt**

independent variables:

sanitation =
   level of sanitation in village (1=0% of households have good
   sanitation, 2=some households have good sanitation, 3=all households
   have good sanitation)

water= level of access to clean water in
   village (1=0% of households have good access, 2=some households have
   good access, 3=all households have good sanitation)

[image: data for 67 villages]

Comment: Welcome to CV! Both models are linear regressions. Note that cases per households is a ratio, so it makes more sense to use a binomial GLM, rather than a normal linear model.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes: The notation you use 'dependent' and 'independent' variable is weird. It may be accepted among 'applied' people but it is weird. You want to predict one variable (the 'target variable') and you have some 'input'/'features' for that prediction. Independent is problematic because it has a precise mathematical definition already and it only applies to collections of random variables, not to a single one!

Now to the actual problem: for using linear regression you need that the input features are numeric. Yours are discrete so that usually is not such a good sign. However, if there is a natural order on the variables (meaning that 0 means no access to water, 1 means a little access to water, 2 means full access to water, this seems to be the case) then still it might work.

For a simple model like a linear regression I would consider 67 villages as sufficient. Note that prev and cases are equivalent and you may NOT use one to predict the others (they only 'vary' by using the known quantity 'numberOfHouseholdsInVillage').

If your simple regression did not give good results then I would strongly suggest to add more features that are related to diarrhea: In which country are these villages? Is it quite 'usual' that there are these outbrakes in that country? How is the weather like in that village? What is the education status of the people? Do they know how to aviod these diseases? When was the last flood? Is it in a rural area? etc.

My first intuition would be that a simple model will find a clear relation like:

1. if the people are less educated (maybe they do not wash hands to often)

or

2. there was a flood or something that destroyed important infrastructure or this infrastructure (hospitals, roads, ...) does not exist/did never exist

then the likelihood for an outbrake should go up.

Comment: Dependent and independent variables are the standard nomenclature in econometrics.

Comment: That's what I meant... maybe they are 'accepted' in some areas but nevertheless it is confusing. I could also redefine 'right' to 'wrong' and vice versa but this will definitely cause a lot of confusion, wrong? So why should I do that and/or stick to that notation? Even worse... when setting this up we usually do not have a clue whether the target variable actually depends on the input features :-) (Don't mean to be rude, I just don't understand...)

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth a try to use tree-based models since they naturally work with categorical variables which seem to be the majority of the attributes in play. Look at, for instance, [this package](https://rpubs.com/minma/cart_with_rpart) in R.

They will output a decision in terms of rules which tend to be easily interpretable depending on your needs.

Apart from that, I coincide with @fabian-werner that additional attributes might help you improve the resulting model.